# Arithmetic exception

Tags: android, arraylist, divide-by-zero, arithmeticexception

Here is my Java code. I am facing an error `"Fatal Exception main"`
I want my app to run successfully.
Please help me. I am new to Android

```
if(queList.size() == question_Counter+1) {


        //  answerList = new ArrayList<String>();
            final int count= dbhelper.getCorrectAnswerCount(answerList);
            count1=count;
            Log.d("bachhhaaaa**********", "Test Activity"+count1);


            String TotalMark  = dbhelper.totalMark();
            Log.d("TEST<<<<<<<<<<<<TotalMark", TotalMark);

            String NoOfQuestion =dbhelper.noOfQuestion();
            Log.d("TEST<<<<<<<<<<<<NoOfQuestion", NoOfQuestion);

            int perQuestionValue=0;
            perQuestionValue= Integer.parseInt(TotalMark) /Integer.parseInt(NoOfQuestion);


            int TotalCountMark=0;
            TotalCountMark = count1 * perQuestionValue;

            String answerString = "Answer";
            for(int i=0;i<answerList.size();i++){

                answerString = answerString+","+answerList.get(i);


            }
            String statusStringOfUserAnswer  = dbhelper.getStatusStringOfUserAnswer(answerList);
            dbhelper.saveOrigionalMarkInDatabase(TotalCountMark,answerString,statusStringOfUserAnswer);  // saves users total marks into database



            Intent intent =new Intent(TestActivity.this,Result.class);
            intent.putExtra("answerString", answerString);
            intent.putExtra("statusStringOfUserAnswer", statusStringOfUserAnswer);
            intent.putExtra("AllResult", count1);
            startActivity(intent);
          finish();
          return;

        }
```

**This is my logcat:**

```
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at com.example.exam.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:132)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-12 03:09:45.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Second line in exception log says its a divide by zero error.check all the places where you do a division,most probably this line "perQuestionValue= Integer.parseInt(TotalMark) /Integer.parseInt(NoOfQuestion)"

Answer (score 3):

**First thing's first, learn to read (and google!) the stack trace error.**

Notice in your stack trace, it says:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
```

According to your given code, the only place you divide is here, so the problem is most likely here:

```
        perQuestionValue= Integer.parseInt(TotalMark) /Integer.parseInt(NoOfQuestion);
```

Basically, `Integer.parseInt(NoOfQuestion)` is returning zero. Now, lets go deeper. Where is `NoOfQuestion` defined? Right here:

```
String NoOfQuestion =dbhelper.noOfQuestion();
```

This means that your `dbhelper` classes non-static method, `noOfQuestion()` is returning 0. You havn't provided your `dbhelper` class in your question, so I can't say why, but there is an easy way to check:

```
Log.v(TAG, dbhlper.noOfQuestion());
```

Hopefully you are familiar with this kind of debugging: doing this will log out the variable that is returned by `noOfQuestion`, so that you can figure out why it is 0.

Let me know if this answer was [helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to you. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask me by commenting, or editing your original question.

Ruchir